# How to insert xml into a node in another xml using XQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery

I have two xml variable say @res, @student in a stored proc in SQL server 2005.

@res contains

```
<Subject>English</Subject>
<Marks>67</Marks>
<Subject>Science</Subject>
<Marks>75</Marks>
```

@student contains:

```
<Student> 
   <Name>XYZ</Name>
   <Roll>15</Roll>
   <Result />
   <Attendance>50</Attendance>
</Student>
```

I need to insert the xml of @res into the node **Result** in @student variable using XQuery.

How to implement that?

Please help.

Comment: Added a "hacky" string-parsing solution which should work for SQL Server 2005 as well - not pretty, but it should work.

Answer (score 33):

In SQL Server 2008, it's pretty easy:

```
DECLARE @res XML = '<Subject>English</Subject>
<Marks>67</Marks>
<Subject>Science</Subject>
<Marks>75</Marks>'


DECLARE @student XML = '<Student> 
   <Name>XYZ</Name>
   <Roll>15</Roll>
   <Result />
   <Attendance>50</Attendance>
</Student>'


SET @student.modify('insert sql:variable("@res") as first into (/Student/Result)[1]')

SELECT @student
```

That gives me the output:

```
<Student>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <Roll>15</Roll>
  <Result>
    <Subject>English</Subject>
    <Marks>67</Marks>
    <Subject>Science</Subject>
    <Marks>75</Marks>
  </Result>
  <Attendance>50</Attendance>
</Student>
```

Unfortunately, the ability to call `.modify()` and use a `sql:variable` in the insert statement was introduced with SQL Server 2008 only - doesn't work in SQL Server 2005.

I don't see how you could do this in SQL Server 2005, other than resorting back to ugly string parsing and replacement:

```
SET @student = 
    CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@student AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
                 '<Result/>', 
                 '<Result>' + CAST(@res AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</Result>') AS XML)
```

Marc

Answer (score 6):

This will work in SQL 2005 and is mostly an xquery solution:

```
DECLARE @res xml

SET @res = 
'<Subject>English</Subject>
<Marks>67</Marks>
<Subject>Science</Subject>
<Marks>75</Marks>'

DECLARE @student xml
SET @student =
'<Student>
   <Name>XYZ</Name>
   <Roll>15</Roll>
   <Result />
   <Attendance>50</Attendance>
</Student>'

DECLARE @final XML

SET @final = CAST(CAST(@student AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '<test>' + CAST(@res AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</test>' AS XML)

SET @final.modify('insert /test/* into (/Student/Result)[1]')
SET @final.modify('delete /test')

SELECT @final
```

You can set your @student variable to @final at that point if you need to do that. The name of "test" for the node was just what I chose to use. You can use any name **as long as it will not already appear in your XML**.

You basically just throw the two XML strings together so that they are both available to xquery at once.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to go back to relational data and than back to xml; something like:

```
DECLARE @res xml = 
'<result>
  <StudentID>1</StudentID>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Marks>67</Marks>
</result>
<result>
  <StudentID>1</StudentID>
  <Subject>Science</Subject>
  <Marks>75</Marks>
</result>'

DECLARE @student xml =
'<Student> 
   <StudentID>1</StudentID>
   <Name>XYZ</Name>
   <Roll>15</Roll>
   <Attendance>50</Attendance>
</Student>'

;
WITH  cte_1
        AS ( SELECT t.c.value('StudentID[1]', 'int') AS [StudentID]
                   ,t.c.value('Subject[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [Subject]
                   ,t.c.value('Marks[1]', 'int') AS [Marks]
             FROM   @res.nodes('/result') AS t ( c )
           ),
      cte_2
        AS ( SELECT t.c.value('StudentID[1]', 'int') AS [StudentID]
                   ,t.c.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [Name]
                   ,t.c.value('Roll[1]', 'int') AS [Roll]
                   ,t.c.value('Attendance[1]', 'int') AS [Attendance]
             FROM   @student.nodes('/Student') AS t ( c )
           )
  SELECT  student.StudentID
         ,student.[Name]
         ,student.Roll
         ,student.Attendance
         ,( SELECT  result.[Subject]
                   ,result.Marks
            FROM    cte_1 AS result
            WHERE   student.StudentID = result.StudentID
          FOR
            XML AUTO
               ,TYPE
               ,ELEMENTS
          )
  FROM    cte_2 AS student
FOR     XML AUTO
           ,ELEMENTS
```

Returns:

```
<student>
  <StudentID>1</StudentID>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <Roll>15</Roll>
  <Attendance>50</Attendance>
  <result>
    <Subject>English</Subject>
    <Marks>67</Marks>
  </result>
  <result>
    <Subject>Science</Subject>
    <Marks>75</Marks>
  </result>
</student>
```

Not exactly your example, but close.